# How can Drive allow us to upload folders of files, with subfolders, when modern browsers only process files one at a time?

Tags: flask, directory, backend, google-drive-shared-drive

How does Google Drive allow uploading file folders and preserve the structures? I've been trying to recreate the same in my web application and it seems that recent browsers don't treat them as folders but treat the files inside one by one. To test this, I tried using dropzone.js.

On the front end, with the Flask framework, I put dropzone.js (works in my web app but not in OS, sorry for the errors, I'm not a full-stack programmer):

After loading a folder, it works as a series of files:

```
127.0.0.1 - - - [27/Sep/2023 17:16:48] "GET /static/images/icons/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Sep/2023 17:16:48] "GET /static/images/icons/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 304 -
request.files: ImmutableMultiDict([('file', <FileStorage: 'Data_engineer.pdf' ('application/pdf')>)]))
request.files: ImmutableMultiDict([[('file', <FileStorage: 'Data_Scientist.pdf' ('application/pdf')>)])))
is_folder(file): False
is_folder(file): False
```